# I am having trouble with a python tutorial for updating dictionaries. I can't figure it out

Tags: python, dictionary

It says: Write a function add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs) where d is a dictionary to be updated and key_value_pairs is a list of tuples where [(key, value)].

It gives hints like: You can iterate over the pairs with, eg, for key, value in key_value_pairs.

You will need to build up a list using append.

It also gives examples of what should happen (inputs and outputs):

```
d = {}; add_to_dict(d, [('a',2)] -> [], d -> {'a':2}
d = {'b':4}; add_to_dict(d, [('a',2)]) -> [], d -> {'a':2,'b':4}
d = {'a':0}; add_to_dict(d, [('a',2)]) -> [('a',0)], d -> {'a':2}
```

Comment: 1 - what have you tried? 2 - I don't understand the significance of the `-> []`.

Comment: [] is the list of tuples which has a key in dictionary d and in the key_value_pairs list. Notice how the 'a' key is present in d and in the key_value_pairs. So ('a',0) goes in there, it is a list of what has to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have to return the old values. So modifying the @demented hedgehog's answer we get:

```
>>> def add_to_dict(d, kvlist):
...     out = []
...     for key, value in kvlist:
...         if key in d:
...            out.append((key, d[key]))
...         d[key] = value
...     return out
... 
>>> d = { 'a': 0, 'b': 4 } 
>>> add_to_dict(d, [('a', 2), ])
[('a', 0)]
>>> print(d)
{'a': 2, 'b': 4}
```

Comment: Yeah, your solution resembles mine, but is better. :)

Comment: Just one thing: you **either** update the dict or insert into 'out' list, right? Not both (if key already exists in dict).

Comment: No either about it. For each of the `(key, value)` pairs if the key already exists you append `(key, old_value)` to the output list and then replace that `old_value` in the dictionary with the `new_value` from the input list. No conditional update, just save the old value and output it if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Smells like homework but what they hey..

```
def add_to_dict(d, kvlist):
    for key, value in kvlist:
        d[key] = value

d = { 'a': 0, 'b': 4 } 
add_to_dict(d, [('a', 2), ])
print(d)

{'a': 2, 'b': 4}
```

Comment: It is a tutorial activity for learning. It says I have to use list.append()

Comment: Righto.. there are better answers than mine now, e.g. Dan D's, so I won't address this.   I hope you've got it all worked out now.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, quite suspicious this is homework... Well, I interpreted the question as requiring to alter the list, removing the tuples, and not updating the dict if the key is already present.

```
  def add_to_dict(d, kvlist):
      rejected = []
      while len(kvlist) > 0:
           key, value = kvlist.pop()
           if d.has_key(key):
                rejected.append((key, value))
           d[key] = value

      return rejected
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down:

> Write a function add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs)

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):
    """
    'd' is a dictionary to be updated
    'key_value_pairs' is a list of tuples where [(key, value)]
    """"
```

> You can iterate over the pairs with, eg, for key, value in
>   key_value_pairs.

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):
    """
    d is a dictionary to be updated
    key_value_pairs is a list of tuples where [(key, value)]
    """
    for key, value in key_value_pairs:
        pass
```

> You will need to build up a list using append.

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):
    """
    d is a dictionary to be updated
    key_value_pairs is a list of tuples where [(key, value)]
    """
    for key, value in key_value_pairs:
        pass

my_dict = {}
my_list = []
my_list.append(('key1', 10))
my_list.append(('key2', 20))

add_to_dict(my_dict, my_list)
```

Now all we have to do is what goes under the `for-loop` inside the function. Which is:

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):
    """
    d is a dictionary to be updated
    key_value_pairs is a list of tuples where [(key, value)]
    """
    for key, value in key_value_pairs:
        d[key] = value

my_dict = {}  # we create a empty dict to be updated
my_list = []  # we create a empty list to append

my_list.append(('key1', 10))  # append the first key, value pair
my_list.append(('key2', 20))  # append the second key, value pair

add_to_dict(my_dict, my_list)  #call the function, and pass the dict and list as arguments.

print my_dict  # see the result
```

Which results in:

```
{'key2': 20, 'key1': 10}
```

EDIT:

Now I noticed that the desired output/result of the function are:

```
[] {'a': 2}
[] {'a': 2, 'b': 4}
[('a', 2)] {'a': 2}
```

Which is weird since functions should **either** return something and don't change the global state, or change the global state and don't return anything.

But if that's what the tutorial wants, here what the code would look like:

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):
    """
    d is a dictionary to be updated
    key_value_pairs is a list of tuples where [(key, value)]
    """
    out = []
    for key, value in key_value_pairs:
        if key in d:
            out.append((key, value))
        d[key] = value
    return out

d = {}
print "->", add_to_dict(d, [('a',2)]),  # -> [], d -> {'a':2}
print "d ->", d
d = {'b':4}
print "->", add_to_dict(d, [('a',2)]),  # -> [], d -> {'a':2,'b':4}
print "d ->", d
d = {'a':0}
print "->", add_to_dict(d, [('a',2)]),  # -> [('a',0)], d -> {'a':2}
print "d ->", d
```

Which returns:

```
-> [] d -> {'a': 2}
-> [] d -> {'a': 2, 'b': 4}
-> [('a', 2)] d -> {'a': 2}
```

Comment: You got the first two right. But the last example is the telling one, you return the wrong value. It states `-> [('a',0)], d -> {'a':2}` and you get `-> [('a', 2)] d -> {'a': 2}`. Rather than returning the new value from the input as in `out.append((key, value))`,  return the old value from the dictionary `out.append((key, d[key]))`.